# Create a user that doesn't use a GUI

Tags: users, multiple-users

I was wondering if it was possible to have one user use a GUI and have a separate user have a more "pure Ubuntu"

Edit: I ended up finding Openbox Desktop Environment which simulates the bare basic that I am looking for

Edit 2: I am still looking for a way to make a console-only user. Openbox was/is just a temporary fix.

Comment: Your original question asks about one user that doesn't use GUI, which reads as console-only user. Your edit now suggests that you were originally looking for very minimalistic GUI. Your question is very misleading

Comment: Openbox is a window manager not a "Desktop Environment". Maybe you mean "Openbox session".

Comment: i WAS looking for a way to make a user console-only user, and i still am. at the time of setup i wanted to get setup and ready for when i make it console user. i should of explained it better in my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Technically , yes. At the very basic level you can use the following commands to create `cmdonly` user:

```
sudo useradd cmdonly                                        

sudo passwd cmdonly
```

Unlike `adduser` command (which is a Perl script by the way), `useradd` doesn't set up user profile or home directory in any way. What you have is the following entry in `/etc/passwd`

```
cmdonly:x:1007:1008::/home/cmdonly:
```

Such user only belongs to only its own group, and has home directory assigned, but not created

```
$ ls -ld /home/cmdonly/                                       
ls: cannot access /home/cmdonly/: No such file or directory
```

Notice that shell is also unset there, which will default to `bash` if you have multiple shells.

As for GUI user, they have privilege to log into both console and GUI. There's no way to avoid cmd login for such user to the best of my knowledge yet. To create gui capable user, it's sufficient to run `sudo adduser newusername`

Answer (score 0):

While login screen if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> you can connect to terminal, login from there and continue working also.